# Takesaki theorem 2.6 clarification

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Consider the following theorem from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebra I":

[image]

Question is simple: in (iv) should the term "closed" be understood as "closed in $\mathscr{M}$"? Or as closed in $\mathscr{L}(\mathfrak{H})$? I suspect it is the former, as it allows us to apply the Krein-Smulian theorem.

Comment: A naive remark about which I'm sure you've probably thought: in iv., because $\mathfrak M$ is $\sigma$-weakly closed, being closed in the subspace or the total space is equivalent. I don't know if that helps you any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's irrelevant, due to $\mathscr M$ being closed in all those topologies.

So, if $K$ is closed in $B(H)$, this means that $B(H)\setminus K$ is open. Then $\mathscr M\setminus K=\mathscr M\cap(B(H)\setminus K)$ is relatively open in $\mathscr M$.

Conversely, if $K$ is closed in $\mathscr M$, then $\mathscr M\setminus K$ is relatively open. That is, $\mathscr M\setminus K=\mathscr M\cap V$ for some open $V$. Then
$$
B(H)\setminus K=(B(H)\setminus\mathscr M)\cup(\mathscr M\setminus K)
=(B(H)\setminus\mathscr M)\cup(\mathscr M\cap V)=(B(H)\setminus\mathscr M)\cup V
$$
is open.

Comment: Once again thanks for your answer! I see that $\mathscr{M}$ is closed in all the $\sigma$-topologies, but why is it also closed in the weak/strong/strong$^*$-topologies?

Comment: It isn't, necessarily. But only the $\sigma$-topologies are used in (iv), since they agree with their non-$\sigma$ version on bounded sets.